# Scoped unique validation for has many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, associations

My hotel has many users, and users might belong to many hotels. I want to have scope validation, i.e., validate the user's username and email uniqueness per hotel. Currently, my models look like this:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :hotel_users
  has_many :hotels, through: :hotel_users
end
```

and my hotel model:

```
class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :hotel_users
  has_many :users, through: :hotel_users
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: need to validate username and email how will this works?

Comment: how to handle scoped unique validation if user belongs to multiple hotels and how to validate whether that username is already on hotels.

Comment: yes we can create multiple user with same email but unique for hotels. hre one user belongs to multiple hotels

Comment: Lets say you already have declared your 'hotel_users' table's primary key as a combination of ids. There is a circumstance in yours 'user case' where your system tries to save an already existing relation?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an explicit model for your join table, and then validate the uniqueness on there

```
class HotelsUsers < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :user

  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => :hotel_id


end
```